# lines even during Bios

Tags: windows, bios, gpu

Since I got the blue screen with driver irql not less or equa, matters got worse and I got the lines you see the images.

- Windows doesn't recognize the gpu
- Windows doesn't see anymore the
  Nvidia suite

I checked all cables 
Memory diagnostic found nothing, I
   tried also changing the place of the Ram 
I tried uninstalling the  drivers 
, I tried reinstalling them (failing)

How would you solve the issue?

Comment: I'd try a different GPU.

Comment: The blue screen was maybe because of a power glitch that cooked your GPU.

Comment: The blue screen happened many times.

Comment: Desktop or Laptop?

Comment: I wonder how I can run just on integrated graphics, since my two attempts failed. I enabled iGpu on my Maximus vi hero mobo and at the restart the CPU overheated. At the second try I couldn't even see the bios. Maybe because I still kept the vga socket to the gpu instead of the mobo?

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolves changing gpu. So mine, after about seven year of service, died. I feel curious to know in which way it dies though. I still can use it, even if I get a lot of annoying lines and risk many blue errors.

Comment: Every time I have had one die (which is many), it was due to heat.  Your reason might be different.

Comment: With or without overclock?

Comment: If this question is for me.. both.. but always clear.. fan fail.. overclock.. some overheat reason.